# How to add a column to a pandas DataFrame with values based on matching values in two DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working with two pandas DataFrames. One contains the performance data of different servers for every hour and looks something like this:

| Date | time | server_name | CPU | Memory |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-10-25 | 300 | server1 | 90.2 | 64.4 |
| 2020-10-25 | 300 | server2 | 50.4 | 23.3 |

In this case, '300' in the column 'time' means 3am.

The second DataFrame contains data to errors for the different servers and looks something like this:

| server_name | timestamp |
| --- | --- |
| server1 | 2020-10-25 00:45:04 |
| server2 | 2020-10-25 03:45:04 |

I would like to have a column added to the first DataFrame with the performance metrics, which indicates for every server for every hour if an error occurred at this time. Please note that an error which occurred at 3:45am should be assigned to the row for 3am for the respective server. It should look something like this:

| Date | time | server_name | CPU | Memory | error |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-10-25 | 300 | server1 | 90.2 | 64.4 | 0 |
| 2020-10-25 | 300 | server2 | 50.4 | 23.3 | 1 |

In this case, '1' in the column 'error' would mean that at this time, an error occurred on the server.

I already tried merging the DataFrames on date, time and server_name and many other approaches, but I just don't get the desired results.

Comment: df= pd.merge(left, right, on="server_name"?

Comment: 1. in second df convert timestamp to your 1st df format. 2. then for second df ```groupby(server_name, new_timestamp).count()```, 3. merge result with first df on server_name and time

Comment: I don't want to count the errors for a server at a specific time, I want a binary classification where '1' means that at this specific time a error occurred on this server and '0' would mean that there wasn't any error.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `df1` is your first dataframe, and `df2` is the second one, you could add a timestamp column to `df1` by adding the `Date` and `time` column, and then use `merge_asof` to bind each row for the second frame to a row from that modified dataframe.

From there, you could merge that new data frame into the first one, and a `groupby` and `count` should give the expected result.

Possible code:

```
df3 = pd.merge_asof(df2, df1.assign(timestamp=df1['Date']
                                    + pd.to_timedelta(df1['time']/100, 'H')),
                    by='server_name', on='timestamp',
                    tolerance=pd.Timedelta('1H'))

print(df3)

result = df1.merge(df3[['server_name', 'timestamp', 'Date', 'time']], 'left',
                   on=['server_name', 'Date', 'time']
                   ).groupby(['server_name',  'Date', 'time', 'CPU', 'Memory']
                             ).count().rename(columns={'timestamp': 'error'}
                                              ).reset_index()
```

With your data, it gives as expected:

```
  server_name       Date  time   CPU  Memory  error
0     server1 2020-10-25   300  90.2    64.4      0
1     server2 2020-10-25   300  50.4    23.3      1
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I had to convert the date and time values to datetime and sort the dataframes, but in the end, the code compiled without an error. But the result df only contains the rows where at least one error occurred. I also need the ones where no error occurred, which means that the result dataframe should be as big as the first dataframe with the performance metrics.
I also had to remove the performance metrices from the groupby-clause due to an KeyError. Maybe this is the reason why it only returns rows with a count > 0?